# Catching Java SQLExceptions

Tags: java, jdbc

I do not have a lot of experience in Java and would appreciate if you bring a light on the question.

I have the following piece of code (method) to establish the JDBC connection with a PostgreSQL database :

```
public void establishDBConnection() throws SQLException {

    try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:postgresql://" + dbServer + ":" + dbPort + "/" + 
                dbDatabase, dbUser, dbPassword))
    catch (SQLException e) {
        logger.error("Connection to Postgres Database Failed: " + 
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
 }
```

I expect that the SQLException would be caught by the catch block as soon as the method can't establish connection with the database (server is down). The catch block puts the exception on the console but I see that the same exception is displayed earlier right after the getConnection method execution. Thus, I have 2 quite the same exceptions on the console. See below.

The question is what is the reason for this and how to force the application to display only the exception generated by the catch block.

Logs:

```
Jul 07, 2017 9:11:53 PM org.postgresql.Driver connect
SEVERE: Connection error: 
**org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to localhost:5433 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.**
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:265)
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:49)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:194)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:431)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:247)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
    at excel2db.service.impl.DBConnectionPostgresImpl.establishDBConnection(DBConnectionPostgresImpl.java:38)
    at excel2db.excel2db.main(excel2db.java:86)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:85)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.<init>(PGStream.java:62)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:144)
    ... 13 more

21:11:53.465 [main] ERROR e.s.impl.DBConnectionPostgresImpl - **Connection to Postgres Database Failed: Connection to localhost:5433 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.**
```

Comment: The app server may have additional logging enabled.

Comment: There's a hierarchy of exceptions.  The second one is the root cause.  The console is right.  The JVM prints the complete stack trace where you expected it would.

Comment: You should not have to add any vendor specific exceptions to your code.  That's the whole point.  You shouldn't have to rewrite your app just because you change database vendors.

Comment: @Steve no, of course not. The catch block does display this exception, so it's being caught. PSQLException is just a subclass of SQLException.

Comment: there's a syntax error for       .... to Postgres Database Failed: "  +  'should be'   .... to Postgres Database Failed: " );

Answer (score 3):

There is only one exception being printed in your example: the SQLException being caught. What you think is a second exception is only (as the text shows) the *cause* of the SQLException: Postgres throws a SQLException, which is itself being thrown because there was a network ConnectException when Portgres tried to connect.

This chain of exceptions is very handy when you need to diagnose a failure. It allows going back to the original, low-level source of a problem. Just like, for example, it can be useful to know that you didn't got your mail (NoMailException) because the post office is on strike (OnStrikeException), because the government decided to lower the wages (WagesTooLowException). If you just had the original NoMailException, you wouldn't be able to know the reason why you got no mail, know that it's probably temporary, etc.

In this particular case, you can deduce that it was impossible to connect to the server, and not for example, that the password was incorrect.

Chaining exceptions is simply achieved by calling one of the exception constructors that take another exception as argument (most exceptions do). See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Exception.html#Exception-java.lang.String-java.lang.Throwable-.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response! Based on what I have read above this is expectable and there are no needs to change something in code. Probably expect eliminating the "e.printStackTrace();" statement which is unneeded since the root cause is caught anyway by the Postgres. Thus, the catch block in a generall case should log(describe) an issue at a high level. Please let me know if this is not correct.

Comment: The code as it is is completely useless: it opens a connection and closes it immediately. If it did something useful (let's say, insert a row in the DB), then it should probably not catch the exception at all. Instead, it should let it propagate to signal the caller that the row couldn't be inserted correctly. Or it should catch it, and throw another, higher-level exception, and chain the original SQLException: `throw InsertFailedException(e);`

Comment: Right, actually I deleted a part of code to concentrate only on exceptions. Thank for you comments once again.

Answer (score 0):

You need to load the driver's class into memory. Try This code :

```
try {
    Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");

    Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbc:postgresql://server_address:5432/database_name?user=usernam&password=password);

} catch (Exception exception) {
    exception.printStackTrace();
}
```